# Update resources (xhtml) intellij with weblogic

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic

I've added the exploded ear (with a war inside) to weblogic.
I've set the "on frame deactivation" to: "update classes and resources"
and finally I've started weblogic in debug modus.

But it doesn't seem to work.. Weblogic doesn't seem to know when I change something in my xhtml pages since they are not updated automatically. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It will update on `frame-deactivation` so try by `ctrl+F10`, it ll work for you.

Comment: Well, if I change from intellij to the browser the frame-deactivation should be called.

If I'm using the shortcut i'm getting `Loaded classes are up to date. Nothing to reload`

Comment: if you want to update the classes also then try `ctrl+shift+f9` or `ctrl+f9`. Hope it works. got from http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/correct-intellij-idea-workflow/q